# Zoho Deluge - Read/Get ticket attachment content

Tags: zoho, zoho-deluge

I am currently trying to run a custom function in Zoho Desk that is triggered on ticket creation, targeting tickets created by our support@zoho... email address, that converts incoming emails into tickets.

More specifically, when an email contains a JSON attachment, I would like the custom function to be able to read the attachment and pull the JSON data from the attachment.

Is this possible? Has anyone had any success?

Below is the code I have, thought I was on the right track but run into the error below

```
//TicketID is set as an Argument for the custom function
ORGID = "********";
getthread = zoho.desk.getRelatedRecords(ORGID,"threads","tickets",TicketID);
threadid = getthread.getJSON("data").getJSON("id");
getthreadcontent = zoho.desk.getRelatedRecordById(ORGID,"threads",threadid,"tickets",TicketID);//.getJSON("content");

info getthreadcontent.getJSON("attachments").getJSON("name"); //Prints the Attachment Name (Works)
info getthreadcontent;//.getJSON("attachments").getJSON("href");//Prints the Attachment URL (Works)

response = invokeUrl
 [
 url: getthreadcontent.getJSON("attachments").getJSON("href")
 type: GET
 ];
```

The above code returns this error:

```
{"errorCode":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"You are not authenticated to perform this operation."}
```

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might need to add your Zoho Auth Token to the URL, first, and then make the invoke_url() call.